# Prove that there is a binary vector that remains constant under multiplication from a group of binary matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, vectors

Suppose $G$ is a group of binary 7$\times$7 matrices and $|G|=64$. We want to prove that there exists a non-zero binary vector of length 7, $v$, such that for all element $g \in G, gv = v$.

I have no idea how to approach the problem. I'm guessing that it has something to do with the order of G being 64 and that there are $2^7=128$ vectors in total. But I don't know what to do.

Comment: Can't $v$ just be the all-zero vector?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention that v cannot be zero vector

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: Your condition means that there's a pointwise stabilizer which coincides with the whole $G$, and hence an orbit of size $1$.

Comment: Does "binary" mean "over the field $\mathbb F_2$" or simply "consisting of zeros and ones"? I.e. is the matrix-vector product considered to be binary as well or is it just integer-valued?

Comment: The idea of stabilizer came to my mind too, since $G$ naturally act on vectors by left multiplication. But I don't know why there must be a size 1 orbit either

Comment: Binary means over the field $\mathbb F_2$ here

Comment: This comes from the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem.

Comment: I know that $|Orb(x)|=|G|/|Stab(x)|$, so $|Orb(x)|=1$ means $|G|=|Stab(x)|$, which is just what we want to prove

Comment: You know already that the set containing 0 is an orbit of size $1$. Do you know anything about the sizes of the other orbits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lemma that is both general and fundamental in the theory of (finite) group actions can be easily applied here:

> **Lemma.** Let $p$ be a prime number, $G$ be a $p$-group and $A$ a finite set on which $G$ acts. If $B\colon={}^GA$ denotes the subset of elements that are *fixed* by the action of $G$, the congruence $|A| \equiv |B|\ (\mathrm{mod}\ p)$ holds.

*Proof.* Let $A/G$ denote the set of orbits under the action of $G$. Remark that by the orbit-stabiliser theorem, $|X|\mid|G|$ for any orbit $X \in A/G$, hence any orbit has cardinality equal to a power of $p$. If we introduce the subset $\mathscr{A}\colon=\left\{\{x\}\right\}_{x \in B} \subseteq A/G$ of trivial orbits, it thus follows that for any $X \in (A/G) \setminus \mathscr{A}$ -- i.e. for any *nontrivial* orbit -- we have $p \mid |X|$ or $|X| \equiv 0\ (\mathrm{mod}\ p)$. Since $A/G$ is a partition of $A$ we have the cardinal relation:
$$\begin{align*}
|A|&=\sum_{X \in A/G}|X|\\
&=\sum_{X \in \mathscr{A}}|X|+\sum_{X \in (A/G) \setminus \mathscr{A}}|X|\\
&\equiv\ \sum_{X \in \mathscr{A}} 1\ (\mathrm{mod}\ p),
\end{align*}$$
and it is clear that the quantity on the final row of the above sequence of relations is none other than $|\mathscr{A}|=|B|$, Q.E.D. $\Box$

The more general context of problems similar to yours in which the above lemma can be applied is:

> **Proposition.** Consider a prime number $p$, a *finite* field $F$ of characteristic $p$, a *finite* dimensional *nonzero* $F$-vector space $V$ and a $p$-group $G$ with an $F$-linear action on $V$. Then $G$ fixes at least one nonzero vector $a \in V^{\times}\colon=V \setminus \{0_V\}$.

*Proof.* Since $F$ is finite and $V$ finite dimensional of dimension say $n=\mathrm{dim}_FV \in \mathbb{N}$, we have the $F$-vector space isomorphism $V \approx F^n \hspace{3pt} (\operatorname{\mathit{K}-\mathbf{Mod}})$ whence we infer that $V$ is in particular a finite set. Let us write $U\colon={}^GV$ for the subset of $G$-fixed vectors. Since the action of $G$ is $F$-linear it can easily be shown that $U \leqslant_F V$ is a subspace of $V$, of dimension $m\colon=\mathrm{dim}_FU \leqslant n$.

In order to establish our claim it will suffice to prove that $m \neq 0$, for then we will be able to deduce something considerably stronger than the mere claim that $U^{\times}=U \setminus \{0_V\}$, namely that $|U|=|F|^m \geqslant |F| \geqslant p$ (the equality $|U|=|F|^m$ follows from the isomorphism $U \approx F^m \hspace{3pt} (\operatorname{\mathit{K}-\mathbf{Mod}})$, the inequality $|F|^m \geqslant |F|$ simply from the fact that $m \geqslant 1$ -- once we show that $m \neq 0$ -- and the final inequality $|F| \geqslant p$ occurs by virtue of $F$ having characteristic $p$, since $p$ is by definition the order of the additive subgroup generated by the unity $1_F$ in the additive group $(F, +)$ subjacent to the field structure).

By virtue of the lemma above, since $G$ is a $p$-group and the set $V$ finite, we have $|V| \equiv |U|\ (\mathrm{mod}\ p)$. Since $F$ is of characteristic $p$, it follows that $|F|$ is a power of $p$ (the additive group of $F$ can be regarded as a necessarily finite dimensional vector space over the prime subfield $P$ of $F$, subfield which has precisely $p$ elements). Furthermore, since $|V|$ is also a power of $|F|$ it follows by transitivity that $|V|$ is a power of $p$. Since $V$ is by hypothesis nonzero and thus $|V| \neq 1$, we infer that in particular $|V| \equiv 0\ (\mathrm{mod}\ p)$ which combined with the congruence at the beginning of this paragraph entails $|U| \equiv 0\ (\mathrm{mod}\ p)$. This necessitates that $|U| \neq 1$, which means $U$ also is a *nonzero* vector space and thus $m \neq 0$, Q.E.D. $\Box$

Comment: Wow this is an unbelievably detailed answer. Thank you kind sir!

Comment: @symmetry I am glad it helped, so the pleasure is mine!

Answer (score 0):

Since $64=2^6$, by Lagrange's Theorem the orders of the stabilizers are powers of $2$, and hence (Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem) the orbits have size either $1$ or a proper power of $2$. Now, there's at least one orbit of size $1$, namely $O(v=\bar 0)$; since there's no way to sum up to $128$ with even summands and just one $1$, there must be at least another orbit of size $1$ (*i.e.* of some $v\ne\bar 0$), whence the claim.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I didn't know that stabilizers are subgroups, should have read textbook more closely!